# How to get only HTML content of the page in Java?

Tags: java, html, url

Without the use of any external library, what is the simplest way to fetch a website's HTML content into a string? I had tried, but I'm getting the complete page source, but I only want HTML content.

Comment: If Javascript & css (etc...) is embedded in the page, there is no way except manually extracting it.

Comment: Javascript on sites may be stored in same text file as main HTML content. If that's the case, then you can only forcefully trim the text, like @SteveSmith said.

Comment: how to manually extract through the code

Comment: What do you want to get when you see this `<body style="border: black">`? Do you want to remove that css?

Comment: i want to remove Js like for example there is a link called www.thehindu.com in its page source it have Js but i want to fetch only html

Comment: this is just for testing as this page have the news headline so to view that headline html content i had tried jsoup but it doesnt work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it a bit difficult to achieve this my friend without the use of an external lib.

You actually want to execute the javascript parts of the Html and act like a GUI-less web browser programmaticaly.

If you are to use an external library I would go for http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ that is pretty easy.